# Excel Pivot table functionalities

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a table with thousands of rows of data regarding sold properties spanning over the following columns:
Ref. number (starting from 1 and ending with the last entry)
Agent
Postcode
Price
Date

I am required to display the top 5 agents by sales of properties in the price range £500,000 - £1,000,000 in NW3 in the period 1st April 2018 – 31st March 2019.

How should I go about this? My pivot table does not help me with filtering the price range, unless I put that as a row instead of a filter. The date would also require that and together they are a mess. Not to mention that it displays them all rather than applying that only as a filter.

Comment: Yes, the price cannot be both in the data and filter section of the pivot table. Perhaps making an extra column that categorizes the price (e.g. if price between 500K and 1,000K then range4...) then use that extra column to be the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a 6th column named "Price range" to your raw data.
- Then go to the "Price" column and use 'Number Filter' > 'Between' > `is greater than or equal to` £500,000 **`And`**  `is less than or equal to` £1,000,000
- Enter "£500,000 - £1,000,000" in the newly added column "Price Range" for the filtered entries
- Create a new pivot for the 6 columns of raw data and use "Price range" under `Report Filter` to list the properties you wanted to see
- Add "Date" to the `Report Filter` as well and select the dates.

This should give you the results you need